# Python; How to import methods to a class 'pluginstyle'?

Tags: python, class, plugins, methods, import

I'm trying to make a class that imports its methods from plugin-like modules.

What I want for this class is for it to be able to import functions/vars from modules that are stored in a separate folder, i.e 'plugins'. Is this possible?

i know about `__import__()`, but how can i use it to import so they belong to this class?

lets say i have the following modules in the 'plugins' folder:

```
plugins/pluginA.py
plugins/pluginB.py
```

In these modules i have functions etc. And i want to be able to import and access them in the class. Maybe something like:

```
MyClass.pluginA.some_function_from_A()
MyClass.pluginB.some_function_from_B()
```

or perhaps like this

```
MyClass.some_function_fromA()
MyClass.some_function_fromB()
```

Answer (score 1):

I would break the problem up into two parts: turning a list of files into a list of modules, then extending the class to include functions from those modules.

Brett Cannon has covered [how to import a module from just a file path](http://misc.feedfury.com/content/49574407-brett-cannon-how-to-import-a-module-from-just-a-file-path.html), so I won't duplicate that here… Although I'll suggest that you check out the [glob](http://docs.python.org/library/glob.html) module.

Second, how to extend a class to include the functions from a plugin. I would use something like this:

```
def extend(obj, plugin_modules):
    for module in plugin_modules:
        for export_name in dir(module):
            export = getattr(module, export_name)
            if callable(export):
                setattr(obj, export_name, export)


class MyClass(object):
    … code …

extend(MyClass, plugin_modules)
```

HOWEVER, I will warn you that it's *unlikely* that this is what you want, as the “plugin” functions on `MyClass` won't behave exactly like native methods… If you give more information about what you're trying to do, I might be able to give a more helpful answer.

Comment: By using those two i think i've found the answer, and i've posted it below. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

I've been experimenting and rummaging around with google and i've come up with a solution that could work thanks to the tip about `setattr` and `getatt` from David Wolever and [This page](http://code.activestate.com/recipes/436873-import-modulesdiscover-methods-from-a-directory-na/) by Jesse Noller.

Here's what i have so far, and it appears to be working, needs cleanup and fine tuning though.

```
class MyClass(object):
    def __init__(self):
        pass

    def import_plugins(self):

        plugins_to_import = []
        attribs_to_exclude = ['__builtins__', '__doc__', '__file__', '__name__', '__package__']
        plugins = []
        plugins_dir = './plugins'

        # add the plugins directory to path
        if os.path.isdir(plugins_dir):
            sys.path.append(plugins_dir)
        else:
            print '%s is not a directory!' % (plugins_dir)

        # make a list of the plugins to import
        for plugin_file in os.listdir(os.path.abspath(plugins_dir)):
            #print plugin_file
            plugin_file_name, plugin_file_extension = os.path.splitext(plugin_file)
            if plugin_file_extension == '.py':
                plugins_to_import.append(plugin_file_name)

        # import the plugins to a list
        for plugin in plugins_to_import:
            plugins.append(__import__(plugin))

        # add the attributes to self
        for plugin in plugins:
            for attribute in dir(plugin):
                if attribute not in attribs_to_exclude:
                    self.__setattr__(attribute, getattr(plugin, attribute))
```

One problem now is to figure out how to pass `self` to the imports...